# Не могу сделать resample

Tags: python, pandas

Есть [датасет](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-I43mPSZVuajrnBpy5Mcz-sC_mQKh0pO/view?usp=sharing), проверяла на дубликаты, удаляла одну запись из-за этого.

```
df_2 = df_.resample('D').ffill()
```

Ошибка

> ```
> ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit
> ```

Как сделать `resamle()`?

На отсутствие дубликатов так проверяла

```
df3_[df3_.duplicated(keep=False)]
```

А вот так повторы есть

```
df3_['Период'][df3_['Период'].duplicated(keep=False)]

2       2017-04-07 00:00:00
3       2017-04-07 00:00:00
4       2017-04-07 00:00:00
41      2017-07-26 23:59:59
42      2017-07-26 23:59:59
82      2017-08-23 23:59:59
83      2017-08-23 23:59:59
93      2017-08-29 23:59:59
94      2017-08-29 23:59:59
271     2017-11-12 09:00:00
272     2017-11-12 09:00:00
964     2019-09-04 00:00:00
965     2019-09-04 00:00:00
1244    2019-10-22 00:00:00
1245    2019-10-22 00:00:00
```

Так не помогает

```
df3__ = df3_['Период'].drop_duplicates()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
ВЫБРАТЬ
    ЗапасыОстаткиИОбороты.Период КАК Период,
    ЗапасыОстаткиИОбороты.КоличествоКонечныйОстаток КАК КоличествоКонечныйОстаток,
          ЕСТЬNULL(
    ПродажиОбороты.КоличествоОборот, "0"
        ) КАК КоличествоОборот,

          ЕСТЬNULL(
    ПродажиОбороты.СуммаОборот, "0"
        ) КАК СуммаОборот


ИЗ
    РегистрНакопления.Запасы.ОстаткиИОбороты(, , День, , Номенклатура = &Номенклатура) КАК ЗапасыОстаткиИОбороты
ПОЛНОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ
    РегистрНакопления.Продажи.Обороты(, , День, Номенклатура = &Номенклатура) КАК ПродажиОбороты    
ПО 
    ПродажиОбороты.Период = ЗапасыОстаткиИОбороты.Период
```

Comment: А точно в индексе не осталось повторов?

Comment: Дописала как проверяла дубликаты - не помогло

Comment: Как теперь удалить с учетом этого?

Comment: не совсем понятно что вы хотите сделать... Судя по коду `df_.resample('D')` вы пытаетесь делать "downsampling", но тогда причем здесь `.ffill()` - в случае "downsampling" нужно применять агрегирующую функцию? Что вы хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: Мне нужно разбить строки по дате и заполнить отсутствующие значения нулями

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates(["Период"], inplace=True)` ?

Comment: @svil, похоже вы пока сами не до конца понимаете что должно получиться на выходе, или не можете это понятно объяснить... Можете создать маленький датасет с 5-10 строками такой, чтобы в этих строках были данные за два дня, которые идут не подряд? И привести в вопросе то, что вы хотите получить на выходе для приведенного DF

Comment: Изменила запрос в 1С и получила сразу то что надо с группировкой по дате и суммированием полей по одной  и той же дате через полное соединение 2 таблиц.